# LOOKUP always selects the last number in the column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I Have a list of 40 numbers similar to below

`+-----------+------------+
|     J     |     T      |
+-----------+------------+
|     1     |      123.4 |
+-----------+------------+
|     2     |      223.8 |
+-----------+------------+
|     3     |       23.4 |
+-----------+------------+
|     4     |      443.9 |
+-----------+------------+
|     5     |      143.5 |
+-----------+------------+`

So I want to look up a number in the first column based on the second.

So I am using the following formula (actual sheet has 40 numbers) `=LOOKUP(23.4,$T$43:$T$82,$J$43:$J$82)` in this example I would have expected the result to 3 but it is always 5 (40 in the actual sheet).

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

let use `VLOOKUP()` instead

```
=VLOOKUP(23.4,{$T$43:$T$82,$J$43:$J$82},2,FALSE)
```

because `LOOKUP()` doesn't have the option or the argument for exact match

I hope it'll work for you

Answer (score 1):

Or use Index/match:

```
=index($J$43:$J$82,match(23.4,$T$43:$T$82,0))
```

[image]